# how to change the colour of a button

Tags: jquery, mobile

I want to change the colour of a button to my preferred colour without using role-theme and also reduce the with of the submit button too.

`<button type=“submit“>Submit</button>`

Comment: are you trying to do this on jquery mobile?

Comment: hi, do you fix this issue? Please share you solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" style="background-color: green; width: 300px;">Submit</button>
```

or better use a external style sheet.

```
button { background-color: green; width: 300px; }
```

will style all your buttons.

Comment: The button colour change but the green colour was light and for the width it did not re size it is only the green colour on the button that re size

Comment: Propably you have a conflicting style in your style sheet. Try separating this from the rest of your application.

Comment: Just a note: your first example is also CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button style='background-color: yellow;'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

on jquery mobile you need to do this:

```
<button type=“submit“ data-theme="e">Submit</button>
```

(assumed that you have the default jquery mobile theme)